# Parse complete string in antlr but extract only part of the string

Tags: antlr4

I have this command which is sent by a client to antlr: `"GET CUSTOMER ID 1234"`

Required:

- Parse complete command string to ensure it is valid (For example, if
  antlr receives `"GET CUSTOMER 1234"`, it should throw error.
- After parsing the complete command, return only ID ("1234")

Is this possible in antlr? If yes, how?

Comment: I am sorry what has this got to do with antlr?

Comment: I answered your question (my answer is “yes”). Then I posted a link explaining it is better to avoid asking questions that can only be answered with a yes/no. If you have a more specific question, feel free to edit your original post.

Comment: "How" is implied i suppose. Updated as per your recommendation.

Comment: No I havent got a solution until now. Hence asking for hints.

Comment: My other comment was removed... Someone managed to take offence to it (?). Anyway, my hint is to read the ANTLR manual and/or do a tutorial and give it your best try. Feel free to post a question if you run into problems.

Comment: If you are aware of the solution, you could guide a fellow traveler. I am not asking for ready-made solution or spoon feeding. A hint/link, nothing more. I will further put effort to take it forward. If you are not aware of the solution, ok.

Comment: I suggest you read the "getting started" section from the ANTLR4 repo:  https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/getting-started.md After you've got the example grammar working, try to edit the grammar little by little to get your own language going. Good luck!